# How to compile a specific binary of a Windows App for an OEM?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have an ann app on windows phone, but now my company wants to *pre-install* it on the production phones.

I want to compile a specific binary for this `"pre-installed"` apps so I can measure how many people uses my pre-installed app.

**The problem:**

I need to make sure that the Pre-Installed app is updateable from the store. So the users can continue to recive updates.

Comment: All pre installed apps (at least on my phones) get updated right after the phone is set up. Probably the pre-installed package will never run, so you won't even notice.

Comment: So the original pre installed app will never run, so i won't be able to store some Data to know this is a pre installed App

Comment: Right. Directly after setup the store notifies about app updates and most user are going to either install them or delete the apps right aways.
As you don't get the chance to write anything to localstorage/settings, you will never know if the installation came from the store or pre installed package.